# WordPress search results not displaying

Tags: wordpress, search

I am using the naked word press theme to build my site with and it all works great apart from when I use the search bar. I type in my search and it takes me to a version of my homepage, but with no content on it.

How do I get my search results to display?

Comment: WordPress search form call search.php in your theme folder. What is there in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a search.php and use this code as an example.

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <h1>Search Result for <?php /* Search Count */ $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); $count = $allsearch->post_count; _e(''); _e('<span class="search-terms">'); echo $key; _e('</span>'); _e(' &mdash; '); echo $count . ' '; _e('acapellas'); wp_reset_query(); ?></h1>
 <ul>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <li>
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
  </li>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Make sure your searchform.php complies with Wordpress's standards, heres an example.

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <span>Search</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>">
    </button>
</form>
```